# Linq Include not working when item has multiple navigation properties of the same class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, ef-code-first

I am working on a project for school, and got a bit stuck on this.

A booking has 3 navigation properties, 1 customer and 2 airports. 
To get the CustomerCode in one of the views for a booking, I can use (*`db.Bookings.Include(b => b.Customer)`*).
When I try to do the same for Origin and/or Destination (*`db.Bookings.Include(b => b.Origin)`*), nothing happens.

I can work around it by finding and setting both origin and destination by using a second query. (*`booking.Origin = db.Airports.Find(id)`*)
But I would like to know why the Include isn't working, and if there is a more elegant way of loading the airports on a booking.

Booking class

```
public int BookingID { get; set; }
public int CustomerID { get; set; }
public int OriginID { get; set; }
public int DestinationID { get; set; }

public string Awb { get; set; }
public string ClientRef { get; set; }
public string Info { get; set; }

// Navigation
public virtual Airport Origin { get; set; }
public virtual Airport Destination { get; set; }
public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
```

Customer class

```
public int CustomerID { get; set; }

public string CustomerCode { get; set; }
public string CompanyName { get; set; }
public string VatNumber { get; set; }
```

Airport class

```
public int AirportID { get; set; }

public string AirportCode { get; set; }
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var bookings = db.Bookings.Include(b => b.Origin).Include(b => b.Destination).Include(b => b.Customer);
    return View(bookings.ToList());
}
```

Context

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

public class AppContext : DbContext
{
    // You can add custom code to this file. Changes will not be overwritten.
    // 
    // If you want Entity Framework to drop and regenerate your database
    // automatically whenever you change your model schema, please use data migrations.
    // For more information refer to the documentation:
    // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx

    public AppContext() : base("name=AppContext")
    {
    }

    public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<Tester.Models.Country> Countries { get; set; }

    public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<Tester.Models.Airport> Airports { get; set; }

    public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<Tester.Models.Customer> Customers { get; set; }

    public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<Tester.Models.Booking> Bookings { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand this line: `db.Airports.Include(b => b.Origin)`.  From the `Airport` model you try to include a  property of `Booking`? If it's just a typo, can you tell me if you have any fluent mapping? You don't have `ForeignKey` attributes specified (not necessary normally because of the Id naming convention, but who knows since you have 2x navigation property) so that might be the issue

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this code. Can you show the context class?

Comment: @AlexanderDerck : it was a typo, should be db.Bookings. I'll try [ForeignKey]

Comment: @YacoubMassad : see update

Comment: I tested your code and it works fine. What do you mean when you say "nothing happens"? Does that mean that the value of `Origin` is null?

Comment: Use SQL Profiler and chec kthe generated query sent to your server? Make sure that your databse contains data for the related Booking and Airport

Comment: @AlexanderDerck : the ForeignKey attribute did the trick.  Thanks!

Comment: @YacoubMassad : the Origin was null, it does work when I add the [ForeignKey("Origin")] to the OriginId

Comment: @Adriaan You're welcome :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Alexander Derck, use **`[ForeignKey]`** attribute.

Booking class

```
public int BookingID { get; set; }
public int CustomerID { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("Origin")]
public int OriginID { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("Destination")]
public int DestinationID { get; set; }

public string Awb { get; set; }
public string ClientRef { get; set; }
public string Info { get; set; }

// Navigation
public virtual Airport Origin { get; set; }
public virtual Airport Destination { get; set; }
public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
```

Answer (score -1):

Origin is a Property. Is not possible use for include. Maybe you not like try like this:

```
     Booking.Include(a=> a.Airport)
```

Comment: This should be a comment, it's not an answer.